# Dynamically Add / Remove Fields - Remove Button not removing Fields

Tags: javascript

I have created Dynamically Add / Remove Fields. The Add button is working perfectly. But when I click the remove button, it only removes the button and not the fields. Following is my code... Plz help... Thanks...

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading"><center><b>Allocation of Funds</b></center></div>

  <div class="panel-body">

<div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Allocation Items</label></div><div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Amount</label></div><div class="col-md-2"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div></div>

<div id="fund-allocation-fields">

</div>

  </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    //fadeout selected item and remove
    $(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){ 
            $(this).empty();
            return false;
        });
    });

    var rows = '<div class="custom-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';

    //add input
    $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function() {
        $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields'); 
        i++;    
        return false;
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML where `remove-allocation-fields` is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Elements in the fields template you're cloning should now have ID. Remember that a document should not have duplicate IDs?
- Use `.closest(".custom-fields")` when removing the button's `.custom-field` element wrapper.
- Remove `i++`
- Instead of delegating clicks down far to `document` use a static nearest wrapper `$(".panel").on('click', '.js-remove', f...`
- No need to `return false;` in your case. `Event.preventDefault()` is good enough (if even needed since you don't have any `<form>` element and you're using `type="button"` buttons.)

```js
var field = `
<div class="custom-fields">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger js-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>REMOVE</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
`;


jQuery(function($) {

  //fadeout selected item and remove
  $(".panel").on('click', '.js-remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".custom-fields").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

  //add input
  $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function(e) {
    $(field).appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields').fadeIn("slow");
  });

});
```

```css
#fund-allocation-fields{background: #eee; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <center><b>Allocation of Funds</b></center>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Allocation Items</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Amount</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>ADD</button></div>
    </div>

    <div id="fund-allocation-fields">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$(this).empty()` you need to do `$(this).parent().empty()`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <center><b>Allocation of Funds</b></center>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Allocation Items</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Amount</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>
    </div>

    <div id="fund-allocation-fields">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //fadeout selected item and remove
    $(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).parent().empty();
        return false;
      });
    });

    var rows = '<div class="custom-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';

    //add input
    $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function() {
      $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields');
      i++;
      return false;
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `.parent()` JS should not broke if we change HTML

Comment: @shawon191 Thanks Shawon Working perfectly... :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `#remove-allocation-fields` to a class rather than id i.e `.remove-allocation-fields` both in the JavaScript and appended HTML